# How to automate Mouse hover action in webdriver/java/kendo ui

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver, kendo-ui, webdriver

I  want to automate mouse hover function for my project. Scenario: there is a text box, if I hover on it, the edit icon will become enabled and I have to click that icon.

Comment: done anything so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform hover operations using the actions class...I have used jquery to click on the element..I took the location from the xpath you provided in the comment section as there is no **divheader_1** in HTML source provided..

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

WebElement Hover_textbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txttab_2']"));

actions.moveToElement(Hover_textbox);

actions.perform();

//if there is only one span inside the div divheader_1

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('divheader_1').getElementsByTagName('span');");

//wait until page loads

Comment: Thanks for the reply vicky.....   Actions actions = newActions(driver);                                         WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txttab_2']"));
actions.moveToElement(mainMenu);
actions.perform();
Thread.sleep(3000);  / till this my code is working  //  
                                                                                                      WebElement subMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='divheader_1']/div[2]/div[1]/div/span"));
actions.moveToElement(subMenu);
actions.click().build().perform();

Comment: I can able to enable the text box edit option, i can't able to click it..... element not visible error is showing (chrome)

Comment: please share the HTML source for that submenu element ...so that we can try other options

Comment: <div class="final_textarea"><div class="tab_lable_right"><textarea rows="2" cols="50" id="txttab_2" readonly="readonly" class="input col_10 input_medium box_radius clscopypaste" oncopy="return false"oncut="return false" data-columnid="20" data-columnname="Member Services Link" data-preval="ABC insurance">ABC insurance</textarea></div><span data-columnid="20"data-columnname="Member Services Link"data-preval="text" class="icon_edit ClsUpdate"></span></div>

Comment: I have edited my above code...I have used Jquery to click on the element.If jquery is not used/loaded in the site the above code will not work.so kindly get back if jquery is not used in your site.If jquery is used check whether the selector used in the above code is the same as the  one in DOM

Comment: Thanks vicky....Its not a jquery, we have used kendo ui for that option..itz different form jquery..

Comment: @ShanmugaRaj can u pls provide the HTML source for the entire div @id='divheader_1 which u have used as xpath in the above comment..i couldn't find the div in the above HTML source

Comment: I have edited by code...I have used javascript to click on the element.I assume that there is only one span inside the div[divheader_1]...If there are more span tags inside the div pls let me know so that i can change it

Comment: Am getting timeout error.........................Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=40.0.2214.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.13.307647 (5a7d0541ebc58e69994a6fb2ed930f45261f3c29),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 59 milliseconds

Comment: Code i used.....WebElement weblinktab = driver.findElement(By.linkText("WEB LINK AND CARD COPY"));
weblinktab.click();
Thread.sleep(10000);
WebElement webelement= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txttab_2']"));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(webelement).perform();//This opens menu list
Thread.sleep(15000);//Holds menu
//This web element is the option you have to click
WebElement webelement1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.icon_edit.ClsUpdate"));
Actions act1 = new Actions(driver);
act1.moveToElement(webelement1).perform();
          webelement1.click();

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
/**
     * Function to hover over the designated element
     * 
     * @param driver
     *            -WebDriver currently in use by script
     * @param by
     *            -By identifying the element to hover over
     */
    protected static void hoverOverElement(WebDriver driver, By by) {
       new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(by)).perform();

    }
```